# JSS 16/18 for Sitecore 10

Tags: jss

According to Sitecore JSS documentation, JSS 16 and 18 are only supported by Sitecore 10.1+. As Next.JS is only supported by JSS 16+, is there any way to make JSS 16 work on Sitecore 10.0 or only Next.JS to work in Sitecore 10.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Next.js SDK depends on GraphQL APIs introduced in Headless Services 16.0, which is [only supported](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0541788) on Sitecore 10.1. Thus you must upgrade to Sitecore 10.1 to use Next.js with Sitecore XM/XP.